# Start new process group in .xinitrc

Tags: shell, process, xinit, process-groups

I have a statusbar (lemonbar) to which I pipe the output of a couple of scripts (time, battery, volume, etc.). These scripts, and the statusbar itself, are all started in a single bash script `statusbar`. When the `statusbar` process is killed, it cleans up after itself by attempting to kill its children, like so:

```
trap "trap - SIGTERM && kill -- -$$" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
```

This all works fine if I call `statusbar` in a terminal, and then quit it with a SIGTERM signal.

However, when I start `statusbar` in my `.xinitrc` file like this: `statusbar &`, the `statusbar` script is not able to clean up after itself anymore. The reason for this is that it is in the same process group as the `.xinitrc` script, together with all the other processes that are started there. I discovered this by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392155) answer.

The question is: can I put the `statusbar` process and all its children in their own process group from `.xinitrc`, so that it can clean up after itself nicely? Alternative, maybe there is a different way of killing all the children of `statusbar`?

P.S.: I realize that wanting to cleanly kill a statusbar is not very common. However, I would like to do it so that I can restart it easily and eventually change my colour theme dynamically, without having to exit X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `setsid` (part of the `util-linux` package)
in the `.xinitrc` to start the script in a new session:

```
setsid statusbar
```

but will it still receive your signals?

Comment: That works exactly as intended for me, thank!